# Dart unit test not working with content-shell

Tags: dart, dart-html

I have dart unit tests written using `test: '>=0.12.1 <0.13.0'` library. When I try to run tests using Dartium it works perfectly, but using content-shell it throws error.

```
pub run test test/unit -p content-shell
Failed to start content shell: Bad state: Stream has already been listened to..
```

I'm using ubuntu machine and content shell is in path.

Comment: we're having same/similar issues on windows machines... but works on OSX w/dart stuff installed via brew.

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest version of `test` and content_shell?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes. I have downloaded content-shell from link specified in test package. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test

Comment: I think you should file an issue in the GitHub repo of the test package.

Comment: Added issue in GitHub repo. https://github.com/dart-lang/test/issues/276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded the dart and content-shell version to 1.11 and its working now.